# Config File Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to train object detection api using `ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config` but look at loss value. this model can't train perfectly. anyone can help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you training on coco? You should share your custom modified config file and also include additional information like number of training samples, classes.

Comment: Yes, Correct ! . this my config file https://github.com/anthoniusadi/tf2-ssdmobilenetv2/blob/main/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config

Answer (score 0):

I had the same "issue" after following an tf object detection api step-by-step guide. Maybe it's a little bit too late for you, but I hope to save the time someone else: You simply need to adjust the learning rate. The tutorial I read was one of the top 10 Google search results for "tf object detection api training" and they didn't adjust the learning rate which is too high for some models (if you just copied the pipeline file as mentioned there)

Please take a look at your [config file (line 162)](https://github.com/anthoniusadi/tf2-ssdmobilenetv2/blob/main/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config#L162)

```
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .8
          total_steps: 20000
          warmup_learning_rate: 0.13333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
```

warmup_steps means that you usually train your model the first (in this case) 2000 steps with a lower learning rate to slowly adjust the pretrained weights for fitting the new challange. I saw some good results with `warmup_learning_rate: 0.0005` and `learning_rate_base: 0.008` obviously this depends on your data and the total steps of your training but 0.1333 and 0.8 are simply to high.

Comment: Thank's , i'll try soon